# PHP - multidimensional array from arrays

Tags: php, arrays, csv, multidimensional-array

I've got 6 arrays - 1 with name and 5 with some properties - which should be assigned to that name. All values are of course in order.  I'd like to make a 2-dimensional array with will be later put into CSV and the result should be as on the table here:

[image: Table on TinyPic]

I guess that i have to do 2 loops here, but I can't make them work.  How to construct such array?

**Solution found**

I've connected all arrays:

```
$final_array = array($nazwa_array,$new_ilosc_array,$new_koszt_array,$new_cena_lifo_array,$new_cena_fifo_array,$new_rodzaj_array);
```

I've found a matrix transposition function, which returns array in correct order:

```
function transpose($array) {
    array_unshift($array, null);
    return call_user_func_array('array_map', $array);
```

}

Comment: Show us some code please and include image in question body, not as external source.

Answer (score 1):

```
$a = array();
foreach ( $names AS $key => $value ) {
    $a[$key]['name'] = $value;
    $a[$key]['property1'] = $value.'->'.$property1_array[$key];
    $a[$key]['property2'] = $value.'->'.$property2_array[$key];
    $a[$key]['property3'] = $value.'->'.$property3_array[$key];
    $a[$key]['property4'] = $value.'->'.$property4_array[$key];
    $a[$key]['property5'] = $value.'->'.$property5_array[$key];
}
```